# Save pdf generated by javascript page at documents dir

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf

I have a uiwebview window that displays a webpage. The user enters some login data and the webpage creates a pdf file, which takes about 15 sec. The file is thereafter shown at the uiwebview.
Now the problem is, that every attempt to save the pdf (or get a url to won load it again)  results in a downloaded file containing some javascript code or the server returns no valid url of the pdf or it downloads a .jsp file.
I did make sure, that loading was finished and I tried all the hints how to grab the url from UIwebview from this forum.
I checked the DiskImageCache at the tmp folder at the simulator and found the pdf content as a file called:tmp-3McaIqN8. I can open this with a pdf reader and it is exactly the file I need.

Is there any way to copy this file to the documents dir ?
Below you see some of my attempts ( I did several more ...

Thanks in advanced!

Jan

```
    NSString *currentURL = self.webView.request.URL.absoluteString;

NSString *currentURL2 = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location"];

NSString *HtmlCOntent = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.outerHTML"]];



NSLog(@"Start Download PDF Url: %@",currentURL);

NSLog(@"Start Download PDF Url: %@",currentURL2);

NSLog(@"HTML content: %@",HtmlCOntent);


// Result:

2014-06-02 16:40:17.680 AppName[53099:60b] Start Download PDF Url: https://domain.com/data/jsp/request/create.jsp
2014-06-02 16:40:17.680 AppName[53099:60b] Start Download PDF Url:
2014-06-02 16:40:17.681 AppName[53099:60b] HTML content:
```

Comment: how does this webview display the pdf? directly? or wrapping it in some html and using an iframe? maybe you're saving that wrapper, and not the actual pdf.

Comment: it displays it directly, as far as I can see. How can I validate this ?

Comment: I did the loading at firefox and activated the inspector. There is no iframe. The pdf opens directly at the firefox pdf viewer or if this is deselected, firefox asks for a place to download.